# Calling a java method from c++ in Android Class ID & Method ID

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, adb

I'm having trouble calling Java from my native C code.  Specifically, I've had difficulty ensuring I've gotten the proper class and method IDs.  I initially had some luck with static methods as opposed to member functions but I've tried both.

As you can see below the simple Java boolean function retTrue returns successfully but I cannot seem to pass the data array properly.

static jmethodID midSetRTS, midClearRTS, midClearRTSb, midTX, midSniffRx, midSniffTx, midClose;
    static jmethodID midgetFTDIDevice;

```
static JavaVM *g_VM;
static jclass cls;
static jmethodID javaMethodRef;


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_rick_myjni_MyNDK_getMyString(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "Hello from native code");

    env->GetJavaVM(&g_VM);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "Attaching to VM thread.");

    jint rs = g_VM->AttachCurrentThread((JNIEnv**)&env,NULL);
    if(rs == JNI_OK)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "Attached");
    else
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "Failed to Attach");

    static int once = 1;
    if (once) {
        jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("com/example/rick/myjni/MainActivity");
        if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
           return (*env).NewStringUTF("Exception");
        }

        cls = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
        if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
           return (*env).NewStringUTF("Exception");
        }

        javaMethodRef = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "retTrue", "()Z");
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "cls: %d javaMethodRef %d", (int)cls, (int)javaMethodRef);
        midTX = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "TX", "([BI)Z");
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "cls: %d midTX %d", (int)cls, (int)midTX);

        if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
           return (*env).NewStringUTF("Exception");
        }
        once = 0;
    }
    bool success = true;
    jbyte txTestMsg[] = {0x18, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0xFF,0x00,0xFF};
    jint len = 16;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "len: %d txTestMsg: %x %x %x %x  %x %x %x %x  %x %x %x %x  %x %x %x %x ", len,
        txTestMsg[0], txTestMsg[1], txTestMsg[2], txTestMsg[3],
        txTestMsg[4], txTestMsg[5], txTestMsg[6], txTestMsg[7],
        txTestMsg[8], txTestMsg[9], txTestMsg[10], txTestMsg[11],
        txTestMsg[12], txTestMsg[13], txTestMsg[14], txTestMsg[15]);

    success = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(cls, javaMethodRef);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, TAG, "Call retTrue succces: %d",success);

    COFFEE_TRY() {
        success = env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(cls, midTX, txTestMsg, len);
        if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
               return (*env).NewStringUTF("Exception");
        }
    }
    COFFEE_CATCH() {
        coffeecatch_throw_exception(env);
    } COFFEE_END();

    if(success)
        return (*env).NewStringUTF("Success");
    else
        return (*env).NewStringUTF("Failure");
}
```

From Main Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ...

    public static boolean TX(byte[] data, int len)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"MainActivity:TX length " + len + " data: " + data.toString() );
        return myFTDIdevice.TX(data,len);
    }

    public static boolean retTrue()
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"MainActivity:reTrue");
        return true;
    }
```

Note the output from android log file:

```
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: Hello from native code
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: Attaching to VM thread.
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: Attached
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: cls: 1050382 javaMethodRef -2012626856
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: cls: 1050382 midTX -2012627024
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: len: 16 txTestMsg: 18 0 d 1  2 3 4 5  6 7 8 9  a ffffffff 0 ffffffff 
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni I/MainActivity: MainActivity:reTrue
08-17 14:55:49.827 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni V/MyJNI: Call retTrue succces: 1
08-17 14:55:49.832 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdead4321 in tid 12432 (Thread-9233)
08-17 14:55:49.872 12389-12396/com.example.rick.myjni W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.880ms
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 'java.lang.Error' thrown in java.lang.String com.example.rick.myjni.MyNDK.getMyString():-2
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from java.lang.String com.example.rick.myjni.MyNDK.getMyString()
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "Thread-9233" prio=5 tid=16 Runnable
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12f7f7c0 self=0xb47c4800
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=12432 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb4509c00
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0x9ce0c000-0x9ce0e000 stackSize=1036KB
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004e6c  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00266509  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0024857f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+158)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b4e83  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b55a9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b8873  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1342)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000c1665  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+28)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 0000162f  /data/app/com.example.rick.myjni-2/lib/arm/libMyLibrary.so (_JNIEnv::NewStringUTF(char const*)+10)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 00001845  /data/app/com.example.rick.myjni-2/lib/arm/libMyLibrary.so (Java_com_example_rick_myjni_MyNDK_getMyString+516)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 000162e7  /data/data/com.example.rick.myjni/cache/slice-slice_5-classes.dex (Java_com_example_rick_myjni_MyNDK_getMyString__+82)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.example.rick.myjni.MyNDK.getMyString(Native method)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at com.example.rick.myjni.MainActivity$3.run(MainActivity.java:150)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-17 14:55:49.902 12389-12432/com.example.rick.myjni A/art: sart/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]
```

Comment: When you print out a jclass cast to an int, you're printing out a pointer to a struct returned from GetObjectClass. You won't necessarily get the same one returned each time for the same class so the pointers won't match up. Also, env->GetObjectClass(jobj); is going to return the myNDK class,  because that's the function the native function is called on, but the function you want to call is in MainActivity, hence the error.

Comment: I've tried to call the MID which was derived from each of the references to cls in this example and they all fail.  I've added static helper methods to the myNDK class and tried to call those too.

Also I don't understand why if they are pointing to the same class that the value of the pointer wouldn't be the same (int cast).

Answer (score 1):

OMG I want to blow my brains out.  It had nothing to do with the method ID or class ID but the arguments being passes.  I had to instantiate a valid java array in C so that it could be passed.

```
   bool success = true;
    jbyte temptxTestMsg[] = {0x18, 0x00, 0x0D, 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x0A,0xFF,0x00,0xFF};
    jint len = 16;

    jbyteArray txTestMsg = env->NewByteArray(len);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(txTestMsg,0,len,temptxTestMsg);
```